# Populate Android ListView with names of items in asset folder

Tags: android, android-listview, assets

I am building a media player based on someone elses code.
The media player plays mp3's from the asset folder.
I have added a ListView to the media player layout.xml and would like to populate this list with the contents of asset folder.
There is currently some code in the main java that takes the mp3 name and displays it in a pop-up. How can I get this information to load into a list instead. Also ietm in list must correspond with track playing.

Here is the java code

```
 //Generate a String Array that represents all of the files found
private String[] getTracks(){
    if(type == 0){
        try {
            String[] temp = getAssets().list("");
            return temp;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if(type == 1){
        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) 
                || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)){
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            path2 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String[] temp = path.list();
            return temp;
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SD Card is either mounted elsewhere or is unusable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//Adds the playable files to the trackNames List
private void addTracks(String[] temp){
    if(temp != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            //Only accept files that have one of the extensions in the EXTENSIONS array
            if(trackChecker(temp[i])){
                trackNames.add(temp[i]);
                trackArtworks.add(temp[i].substring(0, temp[i].length()-4));
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loaded " + Integer.toString(trackNames.size()) + " Tracks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Plays the Track
    private void playTrack(){
        if(isTuning && track != null){
            track.play();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing " + trackNames.get(currentTrack).substring(0, trackNames.get(currentTrack).length()-4), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

And my xml

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/trackNames"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="98dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.74" >
</ListView>
```

How can I populate the list? How can I do it using the code I already have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an ArrayAdapter, or subclass of ArrayAdapter, add your data to it, and set it in your ListView.

Here is an [example.](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Comment: Hi, yes I have searched online tutorials this day. I would like someone on here to explain to me.

Comment: Because I like to have discussion, not read static tutorial as I have all afternoon. Discussion aids my learning of this topic.

Comment: @Will StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not an online discussion.  Read the FAQs.

Comment: Yes questions and answers is 2 way conversation = discussion. So lets move on shall we to the task of answering the question and helping me understand it instead of this it really is an internet bore.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. Search for "RecyclerView". ListView is an old API now that you shouldn't use anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SimpleAdapter version....very similar to ArrayAdapter

```
HashMap<String,String> item;
for (int i=0;i<count; i++){
        item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put( "line1", trackNames.get(i));
        list.add( item );

    }

    sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), 
    list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, new String[] { "line1" },  new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    setListAdapter( sa );
```

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. Is this one using part of the code I provided, or starting  with new code?